# DirectX open-source engine licensing

Tags: directx, licensing, zlib

I would like to publish source code (only source code, no binaries) for basic game engine I created under zlib or MIT license, however it uses DirectX libraries (such as Direct2D, Direct3D, etc.) which are not open-source. I am not going to include them in my project's repository, so that should be fine when it comes to source code itself but wouldn't there be any license conflict when it comes to actually compiling the source code? Will the license cover the binaries as well or not? Should I add to license or readme file some note saying that 3rd party libraries are not covered by my chosen license just to be sure or I don't need to care about this at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about licensing, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not your problem. You are only publishing your source code, and your license only applies only to that. You don't need to say that the license only applies to what the license applies to.